# WCF webservice stop working after upgrade to framework 3.5 sp1

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a wcf webservice on one of my testing servers. Everything worked fine until I upgraded frome framework 3.5 to 3.5 sp1. the wcf web service stoped working and returns the error:

> "Failed to invoke the service. The
>   service may be offline or
>   inaccessible. Refer to the stack trace
>   for details."
>
> "The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (502) Proxy Error
>   ( The specified network name is no
>   longer available.  ).
>
> Server stack trace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response,
>   HttpChannelFactory factory,
>   WebException responseException)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)"

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your windows features were reseted, I had this problem once. Just go to Control Panel-Programs-Turn On windows Features and check all the checkboxes needed in Microsoft .NET framework 3.0
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If, as diadiora suggests, the problem is that the WCF feature is disabled, you may be able to enable it using ServiceModelReg.exe.  `ServiceModelReg.exe /i` should register WCF and update the script maps in IIS.  (Read more at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx).)  If that fails (it may have failed when you installed SP1), that should tell you much more precisely what the problem is.

You might check IIS as well to make sure your service, if it's being hosted by IIS, is still running.